# Is a Beta distribution a continuous version of the Binomial Theorem?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, beta-function

The visual appearance of the PDF for a Beta distribution resembles that for the terms in the Binomial Theorem.  Is the former a continuous variant of the discrete terms of the latter?  Are they related?

Here's what I have so far:

$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{PDF Beta Distribution} &= \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \\
&= \frac{(\alpha+\beta-1)!x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{(\alpha-1)!(\beta-1)!}
\\
&= \alpha \binom{\alpha+\beta-1}{\alpha} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}
\end{align}
$$
compared with the k-th term of the expansion of $(x + y)^n$:

$$
 \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k
$$
now setting $y=(1-x)$, $k=\alpha$, and $n=\alpha+\beta-1$ gives:

$$
 \binom{\alpha+\beta-1}{\alpha}x^{\beta-1}(1-x)^\alpha
$$
The dots aren't quite connected but do suggest a connection.

So are the terms of a binomial expansion related to the discrete steps for a Beta- distribution where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Beta and Binomial are intrinsically related; notably their distribution functions can be expressed in terms of each other. And as mentioned in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Example) wiki page, Beta is a conjugate distribution of Binomial.

Comment: Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/relationship-between-binomial-and-beta-distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, the two distributions are different views of the same model. The binomial distribution is the PMF of *k* successes given *n* independent events each with a probability *p* of success.  The beta distribution is the PDF for *p* given *n* independent events with *k* successes.

Mathematically, when $\alpha=k+1$  and  $\beta=n - k + 1$, the beta distribution and the binomial distribution are related by a constant factor:
$$
Beta(p; \alpha, \beta) = (n+1) Binom(k; n, p)    
$$

[This resource](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/beta-distribution) proves the relationship to the binomial distribution:

> Suppose $\mathit{X}$ is a random variable having a Beta distribution
>   with parameters  $\alpha$ and  $\beta$. Let $\mathit{Y}$ be another random
>   variable such that its distribution conditional on $\mathit{X}$ is a binomial
>   distribution with parameters $n$ and $\mathit{X}$. Then, the conditional
>   distribution of $\mathit{X}$ given $\mathit{Y}=y$ is a Beta distribution with parameters 
>   $\alpha+y$ and  $\beta+n-y$.